# I'm a young girl running for my life through the corridors in this wonderfully frantic 70's-80's short story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The most fascinating thing about this story was these weird icons every few pages, rendered very approximately from memory:

[image: Concentric circle pattern of varying widths between each circle, some lines connect various circles together]

The girl runs, other people run with her or into her, she goes through a door. Then there's another icon, but subtly different. (E.g., with more rings or fewer rings.) As I recall, the girl had no idea what was going on, which was part of the reason for her panic.

The writing was reminiscent of Bradbury's *Frost and Fire* in its breathless rendition of panic and fear and running (but a very different subject, of course.)

When you get to the story's end, the meaning of these icons becomes shatteringly clear.

> Each icon represents a level of an interstellar starship.

I would have read it roughly in the 70's-80's. My memory is that the story was from an anthology of original SF stories. I looked through most of the ~250 anthologies I have here, but failed to find it. I have lost some books to water and rodent damage, so it's possible the story was in one of those.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As I drove to get our Thai takeout food tonight, my brain metaphorically slapped me in the face and said, these icons are "You Are Here" signs.

And I realized that the story title had to be *You Are Here* ! And that quickly led to this isfdb entry: [Alex Eisenstein and Phyllis Eisenstein, “You Are Here” (1977)](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?67429).

I also remembered on that Thai road trip there were two writers, and sure enough, there are.

The publication date matches when I was in grad school haunting the U of I library reading through its large collection of SF. I would have spotted it in the New Books shelf and read it there, which explains why I don't have a copy at home. I didn't buy books I had already read.

I'll get my copy in a couple of weeks, and I'll post the actual icon then.

---

Well, here it is!

[image]

Not too far off from not having seen this for more than forty years.

The book itself has a glued binding so has fallen apart. I'll need to reglue it I suppose. Time to order some padding compound.

Answer (score 2):

Alright. So this might be a wild guess because there's not mant certian indications that this is it. But I still wanted a shot. So it is said that an anime sci-fi film [Neo Tokyo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo_Tokyo_(film))'s first segment is about  [an exploration into the maze of a little girl's mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo_Tokyo_(film)#Labyrinth_Labyrinthos). It is said that the film is inpired by the short novel Meikyū Monogatari of [Taku Mayumura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taku_Mayumura#Novels).

I couldn't find much information about the novel itself tho. I hope this works.

Comment: Sadly, no. It's a short story in a book, in English, with the icons being the only pictures (except for the spoiler on the last page of the story.)